# Programmatically add subscription to SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, scripting, reportingservices-2005, subscription

On my SSRS server I have folder structure like

- folder1

  - subfolder1

    - report1
  - report2
- folder2

  - some_other_report2
  - report3
- folder3

  - report4

I want to that these reports should be copied to client machine according to the same directory structure at a given schedule. I know this can be done by individually adding subscription to each report. But I was looking for a way so that I can programmatically ( using scripting or some tool) add subscription to all the report at one go. Also, if possible, it can be used for other clients as well in the future.

PS: I have searched on SO but the question appears to be old and does not solve my purpose either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it can be done using the SSRS web services the following steps are how I'd do it (sorry no time to code it for you):

1. After getting a reference to the [web service client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005), invoke [ListChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.listchildren), supplying the recursive parameter to walk the directory structure.
2. At each report node, call the [CreateSubscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.createsubscription) method, with appropriate parameters to dump to files.