# Is it possible to add subscriptions?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, business-intelligence

We have a setup so initially report is deployed to the draft folder of the server and then we manually move that report to its folder. The problem is that we have lots of subscriptions that needs to be recreated in the SSRS interface every time and thats annoying.

So is it possible to setup those subscriptions in Visual Studio so each deployed version of the report would have all subscriptions ready to go?

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25262199/3232022)

Comment: Thanks @Indian but that would require a separate project... Is it possible to achieve the same result with only 1 project?

Comment: AFAIK you can't manage subscriptions from a rptproj, writing a script or program that does so through the web service is probably the way to go if you want to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

The project definition has event generator, which will trigger the batch file you difined, then each time you build new version the event will be triggered.
If you want to triggered the event after running some tasks of new build, you could write batch file to trigger the build and run the task.